# How to limit characters in "year" when asp textbox is set to textmode "date"?

Tags: asp.net

I set `ASP` `textbox` text mode to `date`, and noticed its "YEAR" component allows input of up to 9 characters.

My question is, how can limit the year input field to accept a maximum of 4 characters?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="bday" runat="server" 
    TextMode="Date" 
    CssClass="textbox" 
    style="width: 30%; " >
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Are you asking for `Client-Side` or `Server-Side` validation ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MaxLength` property.

```
MaxLength="4"
```

Here is the full code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="bday" runat="server" 
    MaxLength="4"
    TextMode="Date" 
    CssClass="textbox" 
    style="width: 30%; " >
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You mean it allows more than 4 chars?

Answer (score 0):

Take the date as a string and use the substring fonction.. 
for exemple string s1=01 jan 2017 
String s2= s1.substring (7) will give you only 2017
I guess thats the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to prevent the user entering the wrong values ,you should use [`Date Picker`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)..**

> If you want a `Server-Side` validation :

**aspx:**

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="bday" ErrorMessage="Not valid format" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" />
```

**C# :**

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime d;
    e.IsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
}
```

> Or you may need a `Client-Side` validation :

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="bday" ValidationExpression="(((0|1)[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((19|20)\d\d))$"
        ErrorMessage="Invalid date format." ValidationGroup="Group1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of year characters, you need to set the maximum value (`Max="9999-12-31"`).

Note that this format is fixed - do not confuse it with the date format string. This is a maximum value.

Full working example:

```
<asp:TextBox 
  TextMode="Date" 
  ID="txtDate"
  runat="server"
  Max="9999-12-31"
  CssClass="textbox" 
  style="width: 30%;" >
</asp:TextBox>
```